# uibutton on uicelltableView not clicked on ios 9, but clickable on ios 11

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, celltable

I call a method when i click on uibutton of a cell, all works fine for ios 11.1 but on ios 9, when i click on uibutton, the cell clicked not the button

```
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
       indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       ....
            let tapGestureDum = MyTapGesture(target: self, action: 
         #selector(self.playWokout(button:)))
            expansionCell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            tapGestureDum.title = subGroupeCourant.nameDefault!
            expansionCell.playWokout.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

          expansionCell.playWokout.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureDum)


  class MyTapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer {
   var title = String()
 }
```

I can't understand why its work fine for ios 11 not on ios 9

any help will be greatly appreciated

Edit 1

[image: xib]

Answer (score 1):

Check its okay that playWorkout button is disabled or not?

Or

No need gestures. Simply addTarget for button

Comment: i tried                    expansionCell.playWokout.isEnabled = true 
                 expansionCell.playWokout.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playWokout(button:)), for: UIControlEvents.allTouchEvents)          i have the same problem :( not working on ios 9, but all work fine on ios 11 ssimulator

Comment: Use touchUpInside. Is collectionViewCell didSelect is calling?? Or not

Comment: same problem with touchUpInside. yes its didSelectRowAt called instead of the click on button

Comment: Allocate new button and check it once

Comment: when i add a button allocated to cell it work the click but when i add it to stackView its not working,

Comment: i just added a picture of my xib file

Comment: Check your addTarget in button

Comment: when i delete tapGestureDum.title = subGroupeCourant.nameDefault!  the function playWokout is called :(

Comment: Pls Vote for it